# how to share multiple oracle APEX application to end users

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I have around 10 APEX applications built for a business group. I can share all the links for each application to end user but Is there a platform where we can maintain all the APEX applications and send one link to business where they can access all the applications from that link?

Just like SSRS report server where all the reports in one place where end users ca access using only one link.

Thank you
H

Answer (score 2):

Create a "menu" application and let users access that address only.

On the "menu" page, you have various options and create e.g.

- navigation menu list items
- a tree
- a (n interactive) report with links to other applications
- select list item
- a classic report whose template is e.g. alert or card (looks really nice)
- etc.

If all those applications share the same workspace, you can even *emulate* single-sign-on and let users switch from one application to another.